# Bootstrap 3: Tooltip image just after the input field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get that question sign image just after the email address input field and align right to the center of the input field?

[image: glyphicon-question-sign should be just after the input field]

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{translation.TELEPHONE}}:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="jdeRetailer.phone" placeholder="Telephone">
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{translation.EMAIL}}:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="jdeRetailer.email" placeholder="Email address">
        <span style="font-size:1.3em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"  data-toggle="popover" data-content="Info tooltip text here" data-trigger="hover"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form-control class of bootstrap has `width:100%` property. Better way set glyphicon in absolute position with right 0 position.

Just add this property to span:

```
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 15px;
```

and position:relative; to parent of span.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LULezttIQ8PZ1NlkVZ7x?p=preview) is code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by adding style to input to have `display:inline`

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{translation.TELEPHONE}}:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="jdeRetailer.phone" placeholder="Telephone">
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{translation.EMAIL}}:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="jdeRetailer.email" placeholder="Email address" style="display:inline">
        <span style="font-size:1.3em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"  data-toggle="popover" data-content="Info tooltip text here" data-trigger="hover">?</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: making form-control to inline element will impact on responsive width of form-control. Inline elements cant have width in percentage